# how to get an custom error page in laravel 5?

Tags: laravel-5

I need to get an custom error page for example 404 instead of this error,  [this is the error that i get when we try to revisit this page after logging out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fNxpj.png)

Answer (score -1):

https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#custom-error-messages

If needed, you may use custom error messages for validation instead of the defaults. There are several ways to specify custom messages. First, you may pass the custom messages as the third argument to the Validator::make method:

```
$messages = [
    'required' => 'The :attribute field is required.',
];

$validator = Validator::make($input, $rules, $messages);
```

In this example, the :attribute place-holder will be replaced by the actual name of the field under validation. You may also utilize other place-holders in validation messages. For example:

```
$messages = [
    'same'    => 'The :attribute and :other must match.',
    'size'    => 'The :attribute must be exactly :size.',
    'between' => 'The :attribute must be between :min - :max.',
    'in'      => 'The :attribute must be one of the following types: :values',
];
```

**OR**

Specifying A Custom Message For A Given Attribute

Sometimes you may wish to specify a custom error messages only for a specific field. You may do so using "dot" notation. Specify the attribute's name first, followed by the rule:

```
$messages = [
    'email.required' => 'We need to know your e-mail address!',
];
```

watch this as well:
https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals/episodes/12

Comment: i dont want validations for input fields which i have done already, my question was when we logout from a page and click the back button in the browser it takes me to that error page which i have posted in the question instead i want to bring up some other page for example 404.